# How can i compress video during upload on Azure BLOB storage using javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, video, azure-blob-storage

i want to upload video on **azure BLOB** server ,i've **successfully uploaded it using javascript** , but now i want to **compress video size or blocks size during upload**. 
Is there any way to do that. **Thanks in advance**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compress a video on client side web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316791/compress-a-video-on-client-side-web)

Comment: no, its different. i am using azure.BLOB storage , and currently i am uploading video via javascript from aspx page. but video size is too much so i wanna compress it.

Comment: Where do you want to compress it? On the server (in ASP.NET) after the entire file has been uploaded, or in the client web page (in javascript) before the file gets uploaded?

Comment: video data is usually compressed by some codec anyway - you wont get very much compression (even if you could do it easily)

Comment: i want to compress it on web page, client side.

Comment: yes, so you say, how much compression do you think you'll get? 5%? 6%? more?

Comment: @Snack'Eyes the duplicate link I posted shows you how to compress on the web page/client side.

Comment: `video size is too much` - what size do you have? what size do you need?

Comment: videos size is 100 MB or more so i want compressed size nearly 40 Mb or 50 mb. because my site is like Youtube. so videos increases page load time.

Comment: @Snack'Eyes sites like YouTube compress the uploaded videos on the server side after they have been uploaded. Compressing on the client side is now possible but highly experimental due to massive memory usage and slow speed on the client.

Comment: of fine ,then how to do it on server side?

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184437/using-ffmpeg-in-asp-net

Answer (score 3):

> of fine ,then how to do it on server side?

I suggest you could use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) to compress your video file by using azure web jobs.

You could use below command in the webjob to compress your video file.

```
-i {inputfile} -vcodec h264 -b:v 250k -acodec mp2  {outputfile}
```

You could firstly upload the file to your azure web site root path.Then you could add the file name as queue message to the azure queue storage.

If the webjob find the file name, it could run the ffmpeg to compress the video file. After compressed completely, upload that file to blob storage and delete the uploaded file.

More details, you could refer to below steps.

1.Create some new folder to store the ffmpeg exe file and uploaded/compressed file.

[image]

2.Create a webjob project and install the mediatoolkit package from the Nuget.

3.Add below codes to the webjobs function.

```
 public static void ProcessQueueMessage(
        [QueueTrigger("blobcopyqueue")] string filename, TextWriter log,
         [Blob("textblobs/{queueTrigger}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream blobOutput
        )
        {
            //set the input file path
            string inputfile = string.Format(@"D:\home\site\wwwroot\video\{0}", filename);
            //set the input file path
            string outputFile = string.Format(@"D:\home\site\wwwroot\video-compress\{0}", filename);

            using (var engine = new Engine(@"D:\home\site\wwwroot\compress\ffmpeg.exe"))
            {

                string command = string.Format(@"-i {0} -vcodec h264 -b:v 250k -acodec mp2  {1}", inputfile, outputFile);

                //you could change the command value as what you want to use
                engine.CustomCommand(command);
            }

            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(outputFile))
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(blobOutput);
            }

            //after compress delete the file.
            //File.Delete(inputfile);
            // File.Delete(outputFile);

        }
```

Result:[image]